# Change HTTP Port of IBM HTTP Server with postinstall script

Tags: ibmhttpserver, websphere

I am trying to install IBM HTTP Server from an archive. I have extracted the archive and run the postinstall.sh script from IHS root directory which setups httpd.conf and other files.

I want to use port 8080 and not port 80 for http request listening. I know can change that from httpd.conf file after running postinstall.sh script, but is there any way I can pass the argument to postinstall.sh script and it will set the HTTP Port to 8080 and not 80?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to pass in a desired port, but I have taken a note to allow it in the future.

Fortunately, the listening port is only substituted a single time and only in httpd.conf so it can be easily replaced afterwards:

`sed -i -e 's/Listen 80/Listen 8080/' conf/httpd.conf`